# How to add already encrypted password to openldap

Tags: openldap, password

I need to migrate legacy directory-like Mysql data to a new ldap database. Not much hassle except for the passwords. They are stored as sha1 in the Mysql database (I checked I can generate them by typing  "`echo -n "cleartextpassword" | openssl dgst -sha1`").

The problem is I fail to import them in our openldap server.

I'm afraid there might be 2 problems here.

First an encryption / encoding problem: is this sha1 encoding usable as such in ldap at all?

An interface problem: when I use `ldapadd` or `ldapmodify` to enter/update the `userPassword` field, the data provided in the ldif file is re-encrypted. Is it possible to somehow bypass this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it, after a lot of trials.

The sha1 strings I have are so-called hex-digest. To get them into openldap, I first need to convert them back to binary sha1 digest and then base64 encode them.

On the command line one could do that with:

```
echo -n "sha1-hex-digest" | xxd -r -p | openssl enc -base64
```

Then the resulting string should be inserted in the ldif file this way:

```
userPassword: {SHA}base-64-blurb
```

For those interested, this could be done in Python this way:

```
import base64
import binascii

sha1_pwd = "your-sha1-hex-digest-here"
ldap_pwd = base64.b64encode(binascii.unhexlify(sha1_pwd)).decode('utf-8')
print("userPassword: {SHA}%s" % ldap_pwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted the crypt salted SHA-512 algorithm hashes from the linux user accounts to be imported. So I found [(Answer) What are {CRYPT} passwords and how do I generate them?](https://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/344.html) which has more detail, but basically all you have to do is prepend `{CRYPT}` before the usual hash that looks like `$6$salthere$base64hashhere`.

At that link they say to use some perl libs to generate a hash. You don't need to do any of the commands in there to generate anything except to test. (but you'd use `ldapmodifyuser` or another ldif based command, which they don't mention, to actually import the password). But it's useful for seeing the right syntax (`$1$salt...` which is md5crypt):

```
$ perl -e 'use Crypt::PasswdMD5;print("userPassword: {CRYPT}".unix_md5_crypt("password","salt")."\n");'
userPassword: {CRYPT}$1$salt$qJH7.N4xYta3aEG/dfqo/0
```

But the right algorithm wasn't available (which is sha512crypt which looks like `$6$salt...`). there is a `perl-crypt-passwdmd5` package but no `sha2` or `sha512`, so I tested it using mkpasswd instead:

```
$ mkpasswd -S "saltsalt" -m SHA-512 secret
$6$saltsalt$TVLlQcbpFVof5W3Yz4DTP6gRstiNuHwwTt6GLc1E5n0U0aDehy0S5knV8wiOQSpT0Y77vwPZN.Pq.H91p5hVO1
```